# Titanium: Kitchen Sink sample project opens a big black screen as device

Tags: android-emulator, titanium, android

I'm trying to compile the example project Kitchen Sink in Titanium environment for the Android platform, on Ubuntu. When I compile it, it runs and a big full-screen blank window opens with title "5560:titanium_2_WXGA". I am not able to resize it. I think I created the emulated device in eclipse but how can I set it from within titanium studio? If I go to properties run/debug titanium emulator edit, I am not able to set the device features.
thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ran the graphical gui for the sdk (type "android" from console) and I was able to edit the resolution of the emulated device screen in Virtual Devices.